# Returning an average for an array in C# Console App

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, console-application, average

The goal of my program is to take 4 inputs (numeric inputs between 1-100) and create an average based on those inputs using a foreach loop. Currently my code is resulting in individual lines with odd averages. I seem to be overlooking something but can't figure it out.

Input Example: Line "Enter a number between 1-100" is repeated a total of four times, allowing for 4 inputs.

Output should be one line "The average is ##". Based on input numbers.

My current output is "The average is ##" being repeated 4 times displaying each input received instead of the average.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
    class Program
{
    public static double avg(int[] arr)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum / arr.Length;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int SIZE = 4;
        string[] names = new string[SIZE];
        int[] score = new int[SIZE];
        double avg1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a score between 1 - 100.  ");
            score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (true)
            {
                if (!(score[i] >= 1 && score[i] <= 100))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered.");
                    score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            avg1 = avg(score);
        }
        foreach (double a in score)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The average of the test scores is: " + Math.Round(a, 2));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My current output is "The average is ##" being repeated 4 times
>   displaying each input received instead of the average.

Because your `avg1 = avg(score);` function is inside for loop. Put it outside of 
for loop.

---

Code refactoring suggestion:

[Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) in C# provides [`.Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8) function which calculate sum of all numbers in an array.

To calculate average, you just need to calculate sum of array elements and divide it by array `.Length`.

You can do it in single line, no need to write your own function,

```
//Here you don't need separate function to calculate an average
var average = Math.Round((score.Sum() / score.Length),2);  
Console.WriteLine("The average of the test scores is: "+average);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you're looping the `Console.WriteLine` that is why you're getting the output 4 times.

you just have to use:

```
Console.WriteLine("The average of the test scores is: " + Math.Round(avg1 , 2));
```

your snippet should look something like this:

```
class Program
{
  public static double avg(int[] arr)
  {
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum / arr.Length;
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int SIZE = 4;
    string[] names = new string[SIZE];
    int[] score = new int[SIZE];
    double avg1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a score between 1 - 100.  ");
        score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (true)
        {
            if (!(score[i] >= 1 && score[i] <= 100))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number entered.");
                score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    avg1 = avg(score);
    Console.WriteLine("The average of the test scores is: " + Math.Round(avg1, 2));
}
```